# There is a way not to hard code username & pass when sending mail [python]

Tags: python, passwords, smtp, hardcoded

i wanna know if it is possible not to hard code my user name and password in a script that copy a file in the operation system and send it via smtp [gmail]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that best way will be to keep password encrypted, algo is your choice. Then when user give you credentials you check if it match stored encrypted data and then send it. This will take off the step you have to keep plaintext password in any file/database. Anyway you didn't say if you realy need to keep password plain text (but it seems like a case because of remote use), if so then you should use 2-way encryption to avoid plain text passwords - it can be breaked easy but still needs one more step than just read the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Store your data as environment variables or inside a configuration file...

Comment: my idea is that the person who runs the script on his machine won't be able to read the user and pass. is it possible with your idea?

Comment: it looks like security by obscurity, hidding credentials by moving them into weird places doesnt help, not against someone who is better that just a so called script kiddie.

Answer (score 1):

make the script take the username as command line args.

if you import sys, then sys.argv is the list of all command line args, where the first is the name of the python script itself.

Comment: i want the script to run on remote machine without any work, giving the user name and pass as args is not possible for me.

Comment: You dont want, realy you DONT want to take password as a command line argument, if your script needs that then change it to take stream other than ARG. Passwords or other security/important things saved in shell history are realy evil things

Comment: btw. If you feel realy good with security of server from which you are going to run the script then you can use ssh and tell the command to run, just put there ssh key with no password on remote server allowing to run commands from your local one. It is quick and dirty solution and I realy dont reccomend it because of security reasons. Anyway it still can fit your needs